# Create a row in a in a multiindex dataframe

Tags: python, dataframe

original DF

```
                 2022         2023
             In      Out    In     Out
ABC  DOG     7        3      1      10
DEF  DOG     3        14     8      3
GHI  CAT     12        5     2      3
JKL  CAT      2        3     3      1
```

This is a multi index DF. Both the index and columns have two levels. What I need to do is add in a row for the Total. Example Below:

Desired DF:

```
2022         2023
             In      Out    In     Out
ABC  DOG     7        3      1      10
DEF  DOG     3        14     8      3
GHI  CAT     12        5     2      3
JKL  CAT      2        3     3      1
Total        24       25     14     17
```

I tried this:

```
 df.loc['Total',:] = df.sum(axis=0)
```

This received an error:

```
 ValueError: Must have equal len keys and value when setting with an iterable
```

Any suggestions in creating the "Total" row in the desired DF example above? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Try using `values`:

```py
df.loc['Total', :] = df.sum().values
```